# Styled Telerik RadWindow header not allowing drag

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, telerik, styling

A designer did some work and styled the Telerik RadWinodow for Silverlight.  He wasn't able to figure this out and I'm having trouble with it too.

It looks like he applied a style to the WindowInnerBorder template.  It adds a button and some effects.

I believe this is the style, it is applied to a Grid contained in the WindowInnerBorder of the RadWindowTemplate:

```
<Style x:Key="MainLabelRibbon" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Data="M -1,-1 C-1,-1 500,-1 500,-1 500,-1 456,43 456,43 456,43 43,43 43,43 43,43 -1,-1 -1,-1 z" Opacity="1" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                            <Path.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect Direction="275" BlurRadius="7" ShadowDepth="7" Opacity="0.3"/>
                            </Path.Effect>
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF029D05" Offset="0.834"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0ECA0E" Offset="0.432"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF026C02" Offset="0.983333"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF04A906" Offset="0.008"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <UserControl FontSize="18.667" FontFamily="{StaticResource MainFontFamily}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="0,-3,0,3">
                            <UserControl.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect Direction="296" ShadowDepth="2" BlurRadius="3"/>
                            </UserControl.Effect>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </UserControl>          
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

My question is, what do I need to do or is it possible to make the windows draggable when clicking on the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `RadWindow` style, there is a `Thumb` control which makes the window draggable. I think your designer replaced it with a `Button` control and that's why it is not working. Also, using a `Button` here doesn't make any sense.

To fix it is very simple. Instead of applying this style to a Button, you can change the TargateType to point to a `Thumb`. And then inside the style, replace the `Button` control with a `Thumb` control.

Hope this helps. :)